# Frontend App android with jquery mobile and backend with android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I want to create app for android but the Design of my App with jquery mobile and backend with android.

Can I do this work?

Please describe your answer with example.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, basically you need the Install the Android SDK Developer Tools on your machine and create a Webview App.

You are basically creating a Web Browser App that can link to your Jquery Mobile App Just like you will do on a Normal Browser. Once you finish making the Webwvew App and tests are ok then you can install/Distribute the App on the Android Phones and Google Play just like a Normal App.

Here Are some Links for you

Android SDK Developer Tools

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Android Webview Information

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

A video tutorial on how to create a Webview App.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRa4yMjoI7c

You can find more Turorials on How to Install and Use the Android SDK and also on how to create a WebView App if you Search the Internet